# Checking to see if a JtextField is NOT equal to saved arrays

Tags: java, arrays, swing, textarea, equals

Hey guys I'm very new to Java and started in July with an intro to Java class.

I am currently working on a project which is a translator with arrays. The main applet shows 10 words in english that when typed into a `JTextField` outputs the spanish translation of that work.  And vice versa.  The program also shows a picture associated with that word.

The program is all done in that case, the only portion I am missing currently is that if a user inputs ANY other word than the 20 given words (10 spanish and 10 english) the `JTextArea` where translations are displayed is supposed to show "That word is not in the dictionary".

I'm having issues creating an `ELSE` statement that shows this error message.  Here is the complete code. I'm not sure what to do to make it so eg

```
if (textFieldWord.!equals(englishWords[english])){
translate.setText("That word is not in the Dictionary");}
```

Here is the complete code - - - -

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DictionaryArrays extends JApplet implements ActionListener{
String[] spanishWords =   {"biblioteca","reloj",
"alarma", "volcan", "ventana", 
"autobus", "raton", "lago", "vaca", "encendedor"};
String[] englishWords =  {"library", "clock", "alarm", 
"volcano",  "window", "bus", "rat",
"lake","cow","lighter"};
String textFieldWord;
Image[] photos;
ImageIcon icon;
ImageIcon icontwo;
JButton getTranslation;
JTextField entry; 
JLabel imageviewer;
TextArea translate;     
static int defaultX = 10;
static int defaultY = 10;
static int defaultW = 780;
static int defaultH = 50;

public void init() {

  photos = new Image[10];
  photos[0] = getImage(getCodeBase(), "library.jpg");
  photos[1] = getImage(getCodeBase(), "clock.jpg");
  photos[2] = getImage(getCodeBase(), "alarm.jpg");
  photos[3] = getImage(getCodeBase(), "volcano.jpg");
  photos[4] = getImage(getCodeBase(), "window.jpg");
  photos[5] = getImage(getCodeBase(), "bus.jpg");
  photos[6] = getImage(getCodeBase(), "rat.jpg");
  photos[7] = getImage(getCodeBase(), "lake.jpg");
  photos[8] = getImage(getCodeBase(), "cow.jpg");
  photos[9] = getImage(getCodeBase(), "lighter.jpg");
  final JPanel outer = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
  JPanel inner = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
  JPanel viewer = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
  JPanel visualviewer = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
  // here is the main component we want to see
  // when the outer panel is added to the null layout
  //JButton toSpanish = new JButton("English to Spanish");
  //JButton toEnglish = new JButton("Spanish to English");
  final JLabel list = new JLabel("<HTML><FONT COLOR=RED>English</FONT> - library, clock, alarm, volcano, window, bus, rat, lake, cow, lighter"
    +"<BR><FONT COLOR=RED>Spanish</FONT> - biblioteca, reloj, alarma, volcan, ventana, autobus, raton, lago, vaca, encendedor<BR>");
  translate = new TextArea("Your translation will show here");
  imageviewer = new JLabel(icon);
  viewer.add("West",translate);
  visualviewer.add("East",imageviewer);
  inner.add("Center",list);     
  //inner.add("West",toSpanish);
  //inner.add("East", toEnglish);
  outer.add("Center", inner);
  JPanel c = (JPanel)getContentPane();
  final JPanel nullLayoutPanel = new JPanel();
  nullLayoutPanel.setLayout(null);
  c.add("Center", nullLayoutPanel);
  // set the bounds of the panels manually
  nullLayoutPanel.add(outer);
  nullLayoutPanel.add(viewer);
  nullLayoutPanel.add(visualviewer);
  outer.setBounds(defaultX, defaultY, defaultW, defaultH);
  viewer.setBounds(20, 75, 300, 300);
  visualviewer.setBounds(485, 75, 300, 300);
  JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 10));
  entry = new JTextField("Enter English or Spanish word to translate here");
  entry.addActionListener(this);
  entry.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            entry.setText("");
            }});
  getTranslation = new JButton("Translate");
  getTranslation.addActionListener(this);
  controlPanel.add(entry);
  controlPanel.add(getTranslation);
  c.add("South", controlPanel);
  viewer.setBackground(Color.blue);
  controlPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
  inner.setBackground(Color.yellow);
  visualviewer.setBackground(Color.black);
  outer.setBackground(Color.black);
  }

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);



}
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae){
        if(ae.getSource()==getTranslation){
            textFieldWord=(entry.getText().toLowerCase());

            for (int english = 0; english < spanishWords.length; english++){
                if (textFieldWord.equals(englishWords[english])){
                translate.setText(spanishWords[english]);
                icon= new ImageIcon(photos[english]);
                imageviewer.setIcon(icon);
                break;
                }
                }
            for (int spanish = 0; spanish < englishWords.length; spanish++){
                if (textFieldWord.equals(spanishWords[spanish])){
                translate.setText(englishWords[spanish]);
                icontwo= new ImageIcon(photos[spanish]);
                imageviewer.setIcon(icontwo);
                break;
                }
                }   


    }
 }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated guys.  If the top paragraph was TLDR.  Im trying to make it so typing in ANY other word in the `JTextField` (entry) other than the 10 english and 10 spanish words will output an error msg of "That word is not in the Dictionary" in the TextArea (translate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is (obviously) wrong...

```
if (textFieldWord.!equals(englishWords[english])){
```

and should be...

```
if (!textFieldWord.equals(englishWords[english])){
```

Try and think of it this way, `String#equals` returns a `boolean`, you want to invert the result of this method call, it would be the same as using something like...

```
boolean doesEqual = textFieldWord.equals(englishWords[english]);
if (!doesEqual) {...
```

You need to evaluate the result of the method call, but in oder to make that call, the syntax must be `[object].[method]`, therefore, in order to invert the value, you must complete the method call first, then apply the modifier to it ... `! ([object].[method])`

**Updated...**

Now having said all that, let's look at the problem from a different perspective...

You need to find a matching word, in order to do that, you must, at worse case, search the entire array.  Until you've search the entire array, you don't know if a match exists.

This means we could use a separate `if-else` statement to manage the updating of the output, for example...

```
String translatedWord = null;
int foundIndex = -1;
for (int english = 0; english < spanishWords.length; english++){
    if (textFieldWord.equals(englishWords[english])){
        translatedWord = englishWords[english];
        foundIndex = english;
        break;
    }
}

if (translatedWord != null) {
    translate.setText(translatedWord);
    icon= new ImageIcon(photos[foundIndex]);
    imageviewer.setIcon(icon);
} else {
    translate.setText("That word is not in the Dictionary");
}

translatedWord = null;
for (int spanish = 0; spanish < englishWords.length; spanish++){
    if (textFieldWord.equals(spanishWords[spanish])){
        translatedWord = englishWords[english];
        foundIndex = spanish;
        break;
    }
}   

if (translatedWord != null) {
    translate.setText(translatedWord);
    icontwo= new ImageIcon(photos[foundIndex]);
    imageviewer.setIcon(icontwo);
} else {
    translate.setText("That word is not in the Dictionary");
}
```

Basically, all this does is sets the `translatedWord` to a non `null` value when it finds a match in either of the arrays.  In this, you want to display the results, else you want to display the error message...

Equally, you could merge your current approach with the above, so when you find a work, you update the output, but also check the state of the `translatedWord` variable, displaying the error message if it is `null`...

```
String translatedWord = null;
for (int english = 0; english < spanishWords.length; english++){
    if (textFieldWord.equals(englishWords[english])){
        translatedWord = spanishWords[english];
        translate.setText(translatedWord);
        icon= new ImageIcon(photos[english]);
        imageviewer.setIcon(icon);
        break;
    }
}

if (translatedWord == null) {
    translate.setText("That word is not in the Dictionary");
}

translatedWord = null;
for (int spanish = 0; spanish < englishWords.length; spanish++){
    if (textFieldWord.equals(spanishWords[spanish])){
        translatedWord = englishWords[spanish];
        translate.setText(translatedWord);
        icontwo= new ImageIcon(photos[spanish]);
        imageviewer.setIcon(icontwo);
        break;
    }
}   

if (translatedWord == null) {
    translate.setText("That word is not in the Dictionary");
}
```

**Updated**

Okay, you have a logic problem.  You're never quite sure which direction you are translating to.

The following basically changes the follow by not translating the work from Spanish IF it was translated to English

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if (ae.getSource() == getTranslation) {
        textFieldWord = (entry.getText().toLowerCase());

        translate.setText(null);

        String translatedWord = null;
        for (int english = 0; english < spanishWords.length; english++) {
            if (textFieldWord.equals(englishWords[english])) {
                translatedWord = spanishWords[english];
                translate.append(translatedWord + "\n");
                icon = new ImageIcon(photos[english]);
                imageviewer.setIcon(icon);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (translatedWord == null) {

            for (int spanish = 0; spanish < englishWords.length; spanish++) {
                if (textFieldWord.equals(spanishWords[spanish])) {
                    translatedWord = englishWords[spanish];
                    translate.append(translatedWord + "\n");
                icontwo = new ImageIcon(photos[spanish]);
                    imageviewer.setIcon(icontwo);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

        if (translatedWord == null) {
            translate.append("A Spanish-English match is not in the Dictionary\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I would suggest that you replace `TextArea` with a `JTextArea`, but you will need to wrap it in a `JScrollPane`

```
translate = new JTextArea("Your translation will show here");
viewer.add("West", new JScrollPane(translate));
```

Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Basically, this was really painful to try and use for this very reason...

Comment: Ah gotcha I was thinking about it the wrong way. I created an if statement to create that inside the 2nd for loop.  Here is another issue that is coming up though.  After that code, if I input a word that is not in the 20 word list it comes up saying "Word not in Dictionary", but while that message is showing if I type in a word that IS one of the 20 words, the images change, but the error TextArea does not, and keeps saying "Word not in Dictionary".  Would this be fixed with a repaint(); ?

Comment: Ahhh, the problem is...if the "english" is not `null`, then the "spanish" will be, resulting in the error message, give me a sec...

Comment: Ah, that method worked out.  Does a TextArea just make it not worth it to append to it?  And I realize that about nulllayout issue also, I need much more practice with the gui desings and layout managers.

Comment: `TextArea` is a heavyweight component, it will cause you issues when mixed with lightweight components from Swing.  `JTextArea` does provide `setText` as well as `append`.  It was trying something else before I came up with this idea ;)